# How can I fix a 403 forbidden on an apache server using Django?

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I get the following error when I try to access my website:

`Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

My virtual host file looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        Alias /static ~/myproject/static

        <Directory ~/myproject/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory ~/myproject/myprojectapi>
                Order allow,deny
                Require all granted
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my `apache2.conf`is the default file. I am using `Django 1.9 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04`

I have literally attempted most, if not all, the solutions found on the site but none of them are working for some reason. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial and gave these permissions:

`chmod 664 ~/myproject/db.sqlite3`

`sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject/db.sqlite3`

`sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject`

I am also operating as the `root` user.

Please let me know if you require any other information; I will be more than happy to provide it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the WSGI lines:

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess goggest python-path=~/myproject:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup goggest
        WSGIScriptAlias / ~/myproject/myprojectapi/wsgi.py
```

Comment: What happens when you try `./manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: Just 2 questions: (1) can you access `/static` or do you get the same error? (2) Can you show the part of your configuration that maps / to `~/myproject/myprojectapi/wsgi.py` or similar, as at the moment, there doesn't seem to be a mapping between a server URL and `~/myproject` other than for static files.

Comment: @raphv `/static` is not accessible either and for (2) what do you mean?

Comment: @RaviOjha Yes, that's working fine.

Comment: @JeelShah Are you able to access your webpage when you hit the url where runserver is serving?

Comment: @RaviOjha Yes. I can visit `ipaddress:port/route` and it works just fine.

Comment: @JeelShah, something that would look a bit like `WSGIScriptAlias / ~/myproject/wsgi.py`. By the way, if you put '~/myproject' in the Apache config, it may not point to the same '~' as in the command line, because it's a shortcut to the user's directory and may change according to the user.

Comment: @raphv I have added the relevant lines. Okay, I will change `~` to the proper directory and give it another try. EDIT: I change `~` to `/root/myproject..` and still nothing.

Comment: Also, check your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, as by default it doesn't allow serving files outside `/var/www` and `/usr/share`

Comment: @raphv Yes! Okay, I looked into that file and indeed does not allow to serve outside those directories. How can I change that? Should I just mimic `/var/www/` settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is how I fixed (with a lot of help) the problem. 
This answer assumes you have the following project structure:

```
~/myproject
    - myproject
      - ...
      - settings.py
      - wsgi.py
    - myapp
      - ...
      - static
        - myapp
          - ...
```

*Digression*

I was facing the problem where I got an error in my apahce `error.log` which said it could not find `settings`. This issue is most likely caused by an error in your python-path. This portion assumes that you are using the daemon method (recommended by docs).

1. Check your `wsgi.py` file and make sure it says `myproject.settings` instead of `settings` in `os.environ.setdefault(" ... ", " ... ")`
2. Check and double check your python-path which should be something like 
   `WSGIDaemonProcess [any-name] python-path=/home/[username]/myproject:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

This should fix the problem (at least it did for me).

**Fixing 403 Forbidden** (or at least, circumventing it)

The following is the `conf` that did the job for me. It is **not** `apache2.conf` and there is nothing **new** in my `apache2.conf`, it remains the default one.  The following is in `apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /home/[username]/myproject # (1)

        Alias /static path/to/your/static_root    # (2)

        <Directory path/to/your/static_root>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/[username]/myproject/myproject>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/[username]/myproject/myproject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess [any-name] python-path=/home/[username]/myproject:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup [any-name]
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/[username]/[myproject]/[myproject]/wsgi.py

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

</VirtualHost>
```

RE: Points (1), (2)

(1). Change the document root to the head of the directory which contains your django project files. In this case, I changed it to `/home/[username]/myproject`. **Do not** use `~/` for reference. I tried that and it didn't seem to pan out.

(2). If you are serving your static files from the same server then make sure you have set a `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` in your `settings.py` file. In my case, I set `STATIC_URL` to `/static/` and `STATIC_ROOT` to `/var/www/[any-name]/static/`. When you decide to deploy, you will have to run `sudo python manage.py collectstatic`.

Also note that it should be `Alias /static` not `Alias /static/` (note the trailing slash). The docs show `/static/` but that is incorrect and will not work when you try and serve static files (apache does not complete the path).

That's it. All of these steps got my server up and running. If you have any questions, feel free to comment and I will try to help out. Good luck!

Comment: Worked for my adding `DocumentRoot /home/[username]/myproject`